# Django Nginx - Fail to serve static files - No css etc

Tags: django, nginx

I am currently trying to deploy a django project from djangos own runserver onto nginx. The project works fine on `manage.py runserver..` I am using Python2.7, Django 1.6 and RHEL5.

The project lives in /home/nm/openrem/ with the following structure

```
|-- admin
|   |-- css
|   |-- img
|   `-- js
|       `-- admin
|-- css
|-- fonts
|-- img
|-- js
|-- media
|   |-- dicom_in
|   `-- exports
|-- openremproject
|-- remapp
|   |-- exports
|   |-- extractors
|   |-- interface
|   |-- migrations
|   |-- netdicom
|   |-- static
|   |   |-- css
|   |   |-- fonts
|   |   |-- img
|   |   `-- js
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- registration
|   |   `-- remapp
|   |-- templatetags
|-- scripts
`-- static
    |-- admin
    |   |-- css
    |   |-- img
    |   |   `-- gis
    |   `-- js
    |       `-- admin
    |-- css
    |-- fonts
    |-- img
    `-- js
```

(Running `./manage.py collectstatic` seems to create duplicate copies of `js`, `css`,`font`, `admin` and `img` in `/home/nm/openrem` and `/home/nm/openrem/static`. I’m not sure this is what should happen).

Here is the pertinent section of `settings.py` which lives in openremproject

```
ROOT_PROJECT = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0],"..")
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nm/openrem/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.

STATIC_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/media/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT,'static'),
                )

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
                'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
                    )
# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'openremproject.wsgi.application'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'remapp',
    'django_filters',
    'pagination',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'south',
)
```

I have an `nginx.conf` in `/home/nm/openrem/openremproject/`. A symbolic link is created in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` which points to this file.

nginx.conf

## nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    # connect to this socket
    # server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;      # for a web port socket
    }

server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 192.168.197.111;   # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    #Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media/  {
    alias /home/nm/openrem/media;      # your Django project's media files
    }

        location /static/ {
        alias/home/nm/openrem/static/;     
        }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; 
        }
    }
```

For uwsgi: `uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /home/nm/openrem/ --module openremproject.wsgi`

However, the css styling etc does not work when I go to the website (It worked previously using djangos lightweight server). Also when I add an image `/home/nm/openrem/media/image.png` I cannot see  it in `http:/localhost:8000/media/image.png`. How do I serve my static files correctly?

---

Unsure if related but I have noticed that the css only works with `manage.py runserver` when `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`

---

EDIT When I access a page on localhost I get the following on the linux terminal I executed the `uwsgi` command

```
[pid: 1838|app: 0|req: 36/36] 127.0.0.1 () {38 vars in 650 bytes} [Fri Jul 17 09:11:44 2015] GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js => generated 2306 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

This seems to be trying to access the css, bootstrap files

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the `STATIC_ROOT` directory in your `settings.py`:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT, 'static')`

Because of that, your static files are copied to the wrong directory (which is not what you have defined in the nginx.conf)

When you call collectstatic Django will collect the assets in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory. Your assets are being displayed on the devserver (`manage.py runserver`) because then devserver with the `DEBUG` flag set to `True` serves files (found in `static` directories under your project's modules and additional from the directories defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (More information can be found in the official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Finally **do not hard code paths** in your settings, if you migrate your project to another environment you will experience problems:

`MEDIA_ROOT - os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT, 'media')`

Comment: I made the suggested changes and ran `manage.py collectstatic`. I still have no css in my webpage

Comment: Have you configured `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in your settings? and can you confirm that there is a `static` folder after collectstatic in the appropriate path? Also please note, that you need to *restart* your Django process after collecting static files.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS is configured and there is a static folder in the appropriate start. I have killed the aforementioned uwsgi command and reexecuted. Do I have to do something more to restart the Django process?